# Vagrant, error when running vagrant up --provider=docker

Tags: windows, vagrant, docker, bsdtar

I'm trying to test the new docker support in vagrant 1.6. I'm on windows and I've setup my vagrant file but when I run "vagrant up --provider=docker" I get the following:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
==> default: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
default: Vagrant will now create or start a local VM to act as the Docker
default: host. You'll see the output of the `vagrant up` for this VM below.
default:
default: Box 'mitchellh/boot2docker' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
default: Box Provider: virtualbox
default: Box Version: >= 0
default: Loading metadata for box 'mitchellh/boot2docker'
default: URL: https://vagrantcloud.com/mitchellh/boot2docker
default: Adding box 'mitchellh/boot2docker' (v0.8.0) for provider: virtualbox
default: Downloading: https://vagrantcloud.com/mitchellh/boot2docker/version/1/provider/virtualbox.box
default: Progress: 100% (Rate: 2999k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
The executable 'bsdtar' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the %PATH% variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Uninstall Vagrant completely, remove `C:\HashiCorp`.
2. Reinstall Vagrant.

This will fix everything.

Comment: If this answer was correct, please accept it as the correct answer!

Comment: Yes this solved my problem, fantastic. Sorry for being late in picking you as the correct answer.

Answer (score 15):

1. Go to Programs and Features
2. Find Vagrant and Repair

No need to reinstall :)

Comment: Worked for me as well, going from 1.5 to 1.6.3

Answer (score 4):

a fast solution is to attach the path of the mingw binary location to the system's `Path` variable, e.g.:
`C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\embedded\mingw\bin`

Remember to separate path entries with a `;`.

Comment: It didn't help with Vagrant 1.9.7

Answer (score 0):

Download & Install package follow instruction here http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libarchive.htm

then update your Path environment variable to include the installed path of bsd executable, usually C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin